# How to compute the derivatives of multivariate Gaussian expectations with respect to mean and covariance using characteristic functions?

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Consider $q(\boldsymbol{x}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, I need to compute the derivatives of $\mathbb{E}_q[V(x)]$ on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. The results are expected as $\triangledown_{\boldsymbol{\mu}} \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_{\boldsymbol{x}} V(x)]$ and $\triangledown_{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_{\boldsymbol{x}} \triangledown_{\boldsymbol{x}} V(x)]$, but I cannot figure out how to get them.

The Appendix A in the paper (http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/publ/neco_mo09_web.pdf) provides a solution using characteristic functions, but the intermediate steps are missing. Could anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Proof of $\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_xV(x)]$:

By definition of characteristic functions, we can write the $\mathbb{E}_q[V(x)]$ as $$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] =& \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)}V(x)dxdk.
\end{align*}
$$
We compute its derivative to $\mu$ by switching the derivative and integration, and get
$$
\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)}V(x) (ik)dxdk.
$$
We compute its derivative to $x$ in the same way, and get
$$
\begin{align*}
\triangledown_x \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] =& \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)}V(x) (-ik) dxdk\\
&+\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)} \triangledown_x V(x)]dxdk \\
=&-\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] + \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_xV(x)].
\end{align*}
$$
If we have $\triangledown_x \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = 0$, we will get $\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_xV(x)]$.

(2) Proof of $ \triangledown_\Sigma \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_x \triangledown_x V(x)] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_\mu \triangledown_\mu V(x)]$

We compute the derivative to $\Sigma$ as before, and get
$$\triangledown_\Sigma \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)}V(x) (-\frac{1}{2}k^Tk)dxdk.$$
By proving (1), we already have $\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_xV(x)]$, considering  $\triangledown_x \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = 0$. We substitute $\triangledown_x V(x)$ in place of $V(x)$, and get $\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_x V(x)] = \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_x \triangledown_x V(x)]$, since we did not restrict the form on the $V(x)$.
In this way, we "move" the $\triangledown_\mu$ into the expectation.

We can also "move" the $\triangledown_x$ out of the expectation, following the result of (1), and get
$$
\begin{align*}
\triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_x V(x)] =& \triangledown_\mu \triangledown_\mu \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] \\
=&
\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^T\Sigma k + ik(\mu-x)}V(x) (-k^Tk)dxdk\\
=&2 \triangledown_\Sigma \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] . 
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, $ \triangledown_\Sigma \mathbb{E}_q[V(x)] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_x \triangledown_x V(x)] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_q[\triangledown_\mu \triangledown_\mu V(x)]$.

Comment: Note that $\nabla_x \mathbb{E}_q V(x) = 0$ always holds since the expectation will not contain x as it 'averages out' x. Also, your derivative with respect to $\Sigma$ should have the term $kk^T$ not $k^T k$